# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos sin que se repitan en JavaScript y eliminarlos al poner el nombre en el input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, dom

Hola chicos estoy realizando una aplicación en la que se requieren estos puntos, pero solo tengo hecho lo básico, y no se si es correcto, lo suyo sería utilizar ***array push*** para añadir datos y ***splice*** para eliminarlos mientras se escribe en el input, pero, ¿Cómo aplicarlo de manera correcta?

***P.D.:*** el formulario lo tengo hecho en ***DOM***, pero como son demasiados caracteres y no me deja pegarlo, lo he hecho en html.

***Gracias de antemano...***

Aquí los puntos necesarios para que sea correcto :

**a)** Se escribe un ***mensaje de error*** la página (no un alert), si pulsan añadir y
eliminar y no se han rellenado ambos campos.

**b)** Si ***pulsan*** ***añadir*** se crea una nueva línea en el listado en forma de ***tabla***.

**c)** Si ***pulsan*** ***añadir*** y la persona ya está en la tabla, escribimos un mensaje de
error.

**d)** Si ***pulsan*** ***eliminar***, eliminamos la persona de la tabla, o avisamos en caso de
que no exista.

**e)** Si ***pulsan*** ***eliminar*** y la persona no existe en la tabla, escribimos un mensaje
de error.

```js
function guardar() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

if (nombre.trim() == '') {
    resultado.innerHTML = 'No puedes dejar el nombre vacio';
    nombre.focus();
    //alert("ingrese el nombre");
}
if (apellido.trim() == '') {
    resultado.innerHTML = 'No puedes dejar el apellido vacio';
    apellido.focus();
} else {
    var fila = "<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellido + "</td>" + "</td></tr>";

    var btn = document.createElement("TR");
    btn.innerHTML = fila;
    document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="es"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio-2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="ejercicio2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   

<div class="contenedor-principal" id="contenedor">
<form id="formulario" action=" ">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido" id="apellido">
    <button type="button" name="añadir" onclick="guardar()" id="Añadir">Añadir</button>
    <button type="button" name="eliminar" id="eliminar">Elminar</button>
</form>
  <br>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
              <tbody id="tablita">
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El control del formulario lo puedes hacer también con html5 usando los atributos: `required` para que el campo sea obligatorio, `pattern=".*\S+.*"` para no aceptar valores de espacios en blanco sin letras, `title="No es un nombre valido"` para el mensaje de error a mostrar en caso de que el nombre contenga solo espacios en blanco. Usando esto ya puedes deshacerte de los primeros dos `if`, aun así, como no sé si es un requerimiento utilizar JavaScript para eso, incluyo ambas maneras.

Tu código presenta algunos errores, como por ejemplo:

`var fila = "<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellido + "</td>" + "</td></tr>";`

Que debería ser:

`var fila = "<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellido + "</td></tr>";`

Te recomiendo comparar mi código al tuyo para encontrar los otros.

Formulario que valida sin js:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" onsubmit='return false'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="No es un nombre valido">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido" required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="No es un nombre valido">
    <button type="submit" onclick="Guardar()">Añadir</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="Eliminar()">Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

> El atributo `onsubmit='return false'` sirve para que el formulario no envíe los datos evitando así que la página se recargue y cancele el contenido de la tabla, ya que para que funcione esta forma de validación es necesario que los botones sean de tipo `submit`.

Código completo con un formulario que se valida usando js y cumple con el resto de los puntos especificados:

```js
function Personas() {
    /* Devuelve las personas de la tabla */

    let personas = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tabla.rows.length; i++) {
        // Elimina espacios en blanco y mayusculas
        personas.push(document.getElementById('tabla').rows[i].innerText.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    }
    return personas
};

function LimpiarFormulario() {
    /* Limpia los campos y enfoca el primer campo */

    document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
    document.getElementById('nombre').focus();
};

function Control(guardar=false,eliminar=false) {
    /* Controla los campos input */

    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
    var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido');
    var alertas = document.getElementById('alertas');

    if (nombre.value.trim() == '') {
        alertas.innerHTML = 'No puedes dejar el nombre vacio';
        nombre.focus();
        return 1;
    } else if (apellido.value.trim() == '') {
        alertas.innerHTML = 'No puedes dejar el apellido vacio';
        apellido.focus();
        return 1;
    } else if (guardar && Personas().includes(nombre.value.trim().concat(apellido.value.trim()).toLowerCase())) {
        // La persona ya esta en la tabla               
        alertas.innerHTML = nombre.value + ' ' + apellido.value + 'ya esta en la lista';
        LimpiarFormulario()
        return 1;
    } else if (eliminar && !Personas().includes(nombre.value.trim().concat(apellido.value.trim()).toLowerCase())) {
        // La persona no esta en la tabla             
        alertas.innerHTML = nombre.value + ' ' + apellido.value + 'no se encuentra en la lista';
        LimpiarFormulario()
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};

function Guardar() {
    /* Añade una persona a la tabla */

    if (Control(guardar=true,eliminar=false)) {
        // Control no superado
    } else {
        let btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML = "<tr><td>" + nombre.value.trim() + "</td><td>" + apellido.value.trim() + "</td></tr>";
        document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(btn);
        LimpiarFormulario();
        alertas.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
}

function Eliminar() {
    /* Elimina una persona de la tabla */

    if (Control(guardar=false,eliminar=true)) {
        // Control no superado
    } else {
        let indice = Personas().indexOf(nombre.value.trim().concat(apellido.value.trim()).toLowerCase());
        document.getElementById('tabla').deleteRow(indice);
        LimpiarFormulario();
        alertas.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
    <div id="alertas">&nbsp;</div>
    <br>
    <form id="formulario" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido">
        <button type="button" onclick="Guardar()">Añadir</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="Eliminar()">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabla">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Ariel Montes el ejemplo es bastante claro, me falta seguir desarrollando la lógica, y creo que voy por buen camino ! un saludo

Comment: podrías adaptarlo a la versión con array push y splice ? así tendría dos variantes gracias !

Comment: esta puesto con push no me habia fijado hasta ahora de todas formas muchas gracias por la ayuda !